# Opencv findContours() and drawContours() show hollow contours

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

[image]
[image]

the left is "plane.png", the right is "plane_contours.png".
I want to get filled contours without the inner hollow gaps between two lines in the right image.

In other words, I only need the contours of one line.

My code:

```
img = cv2.imread('plane.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray[(gray >= 120)] = 255
gray[(gray < 120)] = 0
cv2.imwrite('plane_gray.png', gray)
con, _ = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
img = np.zeros(img.shape).astype(np.uint8)
for i in range(len(con)):
    cv2.drawContours(img, [con[i]], 0, [255, 255, 255], 1)
    # plt.imshow(img)
    # plt.show()
cv2.imwrite('plane_contours.png', img)
```

I tried to set thickness to -1

```
cv2.drawContours(img, [con[i]], 0, [255, 255, 255], -1)
```

And result is

[image]

I also set `range(len(con))` to `range(len(con) - 1)` to avoid final filling which will make whole image the same color.

But one window and one wing of plane has been filled which is not what I want.

How can I get the correct image?

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

I tried `RETR_CCOMP`. But if I only take outer contours or inner contours, those contours are disconnected.

For example:

[image]
original image

[image]
RETR_LIST

[image]
RETR_CCOMP

Comment: Blue on black has the worst possible contrast, I can't see much in these images. Why not pick a brighter color? Green? White?

Answer (score 1):

Its about the retrieval mode you are using. You chose the `RETR_LIST` which means:

> retrieves all of the contours without establishing any hierarchical
> relationships.

So even in your input image a line looks like only one, it is not one; it includes one contour outer one is inner. There are 2 retrieval modes can solve your problem. `RETR_EXTERNAL` and `RETR_CCOMP`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga819779b9857cc2f8601e6526a3a5bc71):

> RETR_EXTERNAL: retrieves only the extreme outer contours. It sets
> hierarchy[i][2]=hierarchy[i][3]=-1 for all the contours.

This method will eliminate the inner lines.

> RETR_CCOMP: retrieves all of the contours and organizes them into a
> two-level hierarchy. At the top level, there are external boundaries
> of the components. At the second level, there are boundaries of the
> holes. If there is another contour inside a hole of a connected
> component, it is still put at the top level.

This will give you the contours in a hierarchical order. The point is that it only gives 1 parent 1 child. So you can use this info to get rid of inner or outer contours.

Comment: I tried RETR_CCOMP, however, those outer contours or inner contours are separated. I just want to get the connected skeleton.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Wouldn't it be an easier solution to just `For-loop` through the pixels and just **keep only the black pixels**. When black-only pixels are written to a new output image, it will be just the black outlines, no? I don't use Python or OpenCV but maybe you/asker can test that idea as a second possible solution...

Comment: @HaoHuang what about `RETR_EXTERNAL` ?

Comment: @VC.One "through the pixel" any pixel in the whole(binary) image ?

Comment: Imagine the image is an array of RGB values... I mean check every pixel (first to last) in the array, if it has black colour then write black pixel colour at same position of output array.

Comment: i am sorry but not clear to me :(